# Delete AWS codeDeploy Revisions from S3 after successfull deployment

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, bitbucket, continuous-deployment, aws-code-deploy

I am using codeDeploy addon for bitbucket to deploy my codes directly from Bitbucket Git repository to my EC2 instances via AWS codeDeploy. However, after a while, I have a lot of revisions in my codeDeploy console which were stored in one S3 bucket. So what should I do to save my S3 storage from keeping old codeDeploy revisions?

Is it possible to delete these revisions automatically after a successful deployment?

Is it possible to delete them automatically if there is X number of successful revision? For example, delete an old revision if we have three new successful revisions.

Answer (score 2):

CodeDeploy keeps every revision from BitBucket is because, the service needs last successful revision all the time for different kinds of features like AutoRollback. So we can't easily override the previous revision for now, when doing a deployment. But for all revisions older than last successful revision, they can be deleted.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, CodeDeploy doesn't have a good/elegant way to handle those obsolete revisions at the moment. It'd be great if there is an overwrite option when bitbucket pushes to S3.

Answer (score 1):

CodeDeploy is purely a deployment tool, it cannot handle the revisions in S3 bucket.

I would recommend you look into the "lifecycle management" for S3. Since you are using version controlled bucket (I assume), there is always one latest version and 0 to many obsolete version. You can set a lifecycle configuration of type "NoncurrentVersionExpiration" so that the obsolete version will be deleted after some days.

This method is still not possible to maintain a fixed number of deployments as AWS only allows specifying lifecycle in number of days. But it's probably the best alternative to your use-case.

[1] http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/how-to-set-lifecycle-configuration-intro.html
[2] http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/intro-lifecycle-rules.html

Comment: In my experience CodeDeploy gives each revision a different object name, so versioning would not help.

Answer (score 0):

CodeDeploy does not handle a feature like Jenkins sample: "keep the last X [successful or not] runs".
However, with [S3 Lifecycle](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/object-lifecycle-mgmt.html), you can expire (delete) the S3 objects automatically after 3 months for sample.

On one hand this solution is a nice FinOps action when there is a constant activity during the expiration window (at least 3 deployments) by assuring the automatic rollback process of CodeDeploy and reducing the S3 cost.

On the other hand this solution is less efficient when you have spiky activities or worse no deployment at all during the specified S3 expiration delay: in the case of the deployment 12 months after the last one, when this deployment fails, Code Deploy will not be able to proceed to the rollback since the previous artifacts are no more available in S3.

As mitigation, I recommand you to use the [Intelligent Tiering](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-automatic-cost-optimization-for-amazon-s3-via-intelligent-tiering/) it can divide the S3 cost 4 without interferring with the CodeDeploy capabilities. Also you can set a expiration to 12 months to delete the ancient artifacts.

Another last solution is coding a Lambda scheduled by a weekly Cloudwatch Events and that will:

- [List deplyments](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/deploy/list-deployments.html) using using your own critera success/fail status
- [Get deployment details](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/deploy/batch-get-deployments.html) for each
- Filter out again this deployments using your cirteria (date, user, ..)
- Delete the S3 objects using the deployment details

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about keeping previous revisions, you can override the VERSION_LABEL variable to a non-dynamic file name (e.g. "my-application") on upload and deploy. See https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/aws-code-deploy/src/master.

This will cause the previous revision to be overwritten by the next one so there is only ever one revision stored in the S3 bucket at a time.

If you want to delete this revision after deployment too, you can do so with a simple AWS CLI command in a post install script which is included via a hook in the appspec.yml file (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/reference-appspec-file-structure-hooks.html):

```
aws s3 rm s3://bucket-name/my-application <-- The name of your revision goes here
```